# API dont get back call

Tags: python-3.x

Actual code:

```py
from doctest import NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
import dhooks
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import requests
import time
import os
from webserver import keep_alive
import discord
import asyncio
from typing import Optional

keep_alive()

def get_3dhentai():
  # 3D-Hentai
  poster = os.getenv("3dhentai")
  hook = Webhook(poster)
  ret1 = requests.get("https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000&tags=rating:explicit+3dhentai").json()
  if ret1:
      image = ret1[0].get("file_url")
      if image:
          embed = Embed(description=f"3D-Hentai")
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          embed.set_footer(text="Powered by Nico`s Club")
          hook.send(embed=embed)
      else:
          print("No image URL found in the response from API.")
  else:
      print("No data received from API.")

def get_slimegirl():
  # Slime-Girl
  poster = os.getenv("slimegirl")
  hook = Webhook(poster)
  ret1 = requests.get("https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000&tags=rating:explicit+slimegirl").json()
  if ret1:
      image = ret1[0].get("file_url")
      if image:
          embed = Embed(description=f"Slime Girl")
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          embed.set_footer(text="Powered by Nico`s Club")
          hook.send(embed=embed)
      else:
          print("No image URL found in the response from API.")
  else:
      print("No data received from API.")

def get_tentacles():
  # Tentacles
  poster = os.getenv("tentacles")
  hook = Webhook(poster)
  ret1 = requests.get("https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000&tags=rating:explicit+tentacles").json()
  if ret1:
      image = ret1[0].get("file_url")
      if image:
          embed = Embed(description=f"Tentacles")
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          embed.set_footer(text="Powered by Nico`s Club")
          hook.send(embed=embed)
      else:
          print("No image URL found in the response from API.")
  else:
      print("No data received from API.")
    
def get_futunari():
  # Futunari
  poster = os.getenv("futunari")
  hook = Webhook(poster)
  ret1 = requests.get("https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000&tags=rating:explicit+futunari").json()
  if ret1:
      image = ret1[0].get("file_url")
      if image:
          embed = Embed(description=f"Futunari")
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          embed.set_footer(text="Powered by Nico`s Club")
          hook.send(embed=embed)
      else:
          print("No image URL found in the response from API.")
  else:
      print("No data received from API.")
    
def get_hentai():
  # Hentai
  poster = os.getenv("hentai")
  hook = Webhook(poster)
  ret1 = requests.get("https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000&tags=rating:explicit+hentai").json()
  if ret1:
      image = ret1[0].get("file_url")
      if image:
          embed = Embed(description=f"Hentai")
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          embed.set_footer(text="Powered by Nico`s Club")
          hook.send(embed=embed)
      else:
          print("No image URL found in the response from API.")
  else:
      print("No data received from API.")

def worker():
  while True:
    get_3dhentai()
    time.sleep(1)
    get_slimegirl()
    time.sleep(1)
    get_tentacles()
    time.sleep(1)
    get_futunari()
    time.sleep(1)
    get_hentai()
    time.sleep(300)

worker()
```

Error what i have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 113, in <module>
    worker()
  File "main.py", line 102, in worker
    get_3dhentai()
  File "main.py", line 19, in get_3dhentai
    ret1 = requests.get("https://api.rule34.xxx/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=1000&tags=rating:explicit+3dhentai").json()
  File "/home/runner/KaspiV2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please, someone can me tell about my errors or mistakes, because i dumb..

My code should perform the function of an auto-poster, to be more precise, it should search for images in the API and use them for posting via webhooks.

The only thing I realized was that the error was caused by the fact that the API does not send back responses, although if you leave 1 function, then everything is perfect and everything works with a bang, and with 5+ everything works for some reason sad.

Comment: Welcome to [so]). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [mre] for details on how to best help us help you.